# How can I determine if I have cracked drain pipes under the basement cement slab

Tags: drain, cracks

I have a wet wall (just efflorescence and wet spots) on the wall as showed in the picture. I suspect that this is because of a patio that was incorrectly sloped toward the house. That is fixed now and I was told by someone that it will take time till the wall gets dry. Somebody else told me the contrary that the wall should get dry shortly after the source of humidity is gone AND that I might have cracked drain pipes under the cement slab that makes the floor of the basement.

Before I start digging or looking closer to this can anybody tell me if there is any way to rule out this possibility without actually digging?

The interesting part of this is that the wet spots and the efflorescence are stronger away from the supposed source of humidity (drains) represented in the picture below. In winter I have no problems (the light smell is gone from the basement-the spots remain on the exterior wall).No visible signs of humidity in the basement (finished basement)

For more info about this case please see my other posts around here. That will also explain some elements in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have some idea about what pipes may be broken, and they can be accessed from somewhere, you can check the pipes with a camera. It's like an endoscopy for your house.

Some plumbers offer this service, search for it online.

Comment: This must be a very fine crack...I doubt that it will be detected with an inspection camera. I can rent one myself and look.

Comment: You could try to not use the pipe for some time (use other toilets/go on holiday) and see if the humidity gets less, but I guess it's a long shot.